# Cannot access method from superclass when subclass instantiated using Object variable

Tags: java, inheritance

I was practising inheritance and had these classes where Bite extends the Gulp class.

```
public class Gulp {
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("Gulp 2");
        method3();
    }

    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("Gulp 3");
    }
}

public class Bite extends Gulp {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("Bite 1");
    }

    public void method3() {
        System.out.println("Bite 3");
    }
}
```

I am trying to invoke the method `method2()` by creating objects of Bite class(using three different kind of references: Object,Bite and Gulp) as below:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object varObj = new Bite();
        Bite varBite = new Bite();
        Gulp varGulp = new Bite();

        if(varBite.getClass() == Bite.class) 
            System.out.println("Bite class");

        if(varObj.getClass() == Bite.class) 
            System.out.println("Also Bite class");

        varBite.method2();
        //prints what is expected

        varObj.method2();
        //throws compilation error -- cannot find method2()

        varGulp.method2();
        //prints what is expected
    }
}
```

I am getting error when the reference variable is type of Object. It says, it cant find the symbol although the `varObject.getClass()` returns Bite.class.
Could anyone please explain..

Comment: You're missing some object oriented principles. You have to distinguish between the reference type and the actual type of the object. You can only call methods defined in the reference type (Object, Gulp or Bite) but the actually called method is defined by the actual type which is Bite in all cases (buzzword polymorphism).

Comment: It's the type of reference, not the type of object which matters. `varObj` is an `Object` reference and `Object` doesn't have a `method2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler won't let you call methods specific to `Bite` if you declared the variable as of type `Object`.

You have two options:
Either declare the objects as `Bite`, like `varBite`. Or cast the `Object` variable to `Bite`:

```
((Bite)varObj).method2();
```